# Can I trick the jquery text() function to accept html?

Tags: jquery

Can I trick the jquery text() function to accept html and not change the tags to their & equivalent. Something like passing it the ascii values?

I'm trying to return HTML in the label portion of the jQuery autocomplete, which uses the text function internally. There are people who suggest calling an undocumented internal function _renderItem () which I'd rather not do.

Comment: Do you not have control over where `$.text()` is being called?

Comment: Not sure why you have reservations about using an internal undocumented function, yet want to use a public function in an undocumented way...

Comment: I don't have control of the text command. It is in the autocomplete. I have control of the data I send it. I wondered if there's an escape sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to temporarily replace the function, e.g:

```
var original = jQuery.text;
jQuery.text = jQuery.html;

// library code executes

jQuery.text = original;
```

but I have to think there's a better way, for instance, the jQueryUi autocomplete allows for custom html in displaying the results:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

Answer (score 3):

No. And if you can find a way to do it using $.text(), please file a bug, because that would be a security hole.